# If I want to use autoit how can I use in maven project

Tags: java, selenium

Which is the best way to upload file in selenium webdriver with java?

--using send keys
--using autoit
--using robot class

If I want to use autoit how can I use in maven project

Can I upload file in selenium webdriver without giving hardcode path?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use autoit in maven project.

```
String getLocation=Constant.currentDirectory+"\\testExplorer.exe "+ uploadFileName;
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(getLocation);
```

Here uploadfilename is the name of the file that you want to upload
You can create .exe file by using AutoIt Editor.By using the following code you can parameterise the filename that you want to upload

```
ControlFocus("Open","","Edit1")
ControlSetText("Open","","Edit1",$CmdLine[1])
ControlClick("Open","","Button1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below two dependencies in to your pom-
Note: by using Jcob API, you can actually directly write/copy paste autoit script(s) in your selenium code without having it as complied executable exe script..

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>autoitx4java</groupId>
        <artifactId>autoitx4java</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.hynnet/jacob -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hynnet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacob</artifactId>
        <version>1.18</version>
    </dependency>
```

How to use it example-
1.Keep Jacob dll in to your project path and set its path as below-

```
   System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, 
   System.getProperty("user.dir") + 
   "/automation/src/test/java/externalLib/jacob- 
   1.20-x64.dll");
```

2. click on the upload/choose file in ur app with regular selenium click-
   clickOnElement(findElementByXpath(chooseFileBtn));
   wait(2);
3. Now write your code (you need autoIt installed for this and capture script) like below-

   AutoItX autoIt = new AutoItX();
   String title = "Open";
   Assert.assertTrue(autoIt.winWaitActive(title, "Open", 20));
   autoIt.controlSend(title, "", "Edit1", filePath);
   autoIt.controlClick(title, "", "Button1");

Note: AutoIt Controls [controlSend, and controlClick ] will work directly from our code now, and do the job.